# In excel If test passes when value typed manually but fail from a cell

Tags: vba, excel

Using excel VBA, I have constructed a dictionary and populated it. I did my tests and it's well done.
After that, in a loop I had to test if a key exists to do some operations:

```
For i3 = 2 To n 'n is the the number of rows
    If dicos.Exists(ActiveSheet.Range("T" & i3)) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("N" & i3) = dicos(ActiveSheet.Range("T" & i3)) + 1
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("N" & i3) = 1
    End If
Next
```

It doesn't work and I have 1 in all the column N. I tried to test with some values from the column T manually and it finds it!
Can anyone explain to me what I have done wrong and why the test is positive when I type the value manually and it is negative when the program has to take it from a cell (column T)?
Thank you very much.

Comment: try `ActiveSheet.Range("T" & i3)) .Value2`. Also, are you sure that the sheet you think is *Active*, really is? It's best to quaiify worksheets to variables and work with the variable directly to **ensure** you have the exact sheet you want. Like this: `Dim ws as Worksheet | Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") | ws.Range("AT" & i3)`

Comment: It doesn't work with .Value2. And yes, the active sheet is what I think it is, because `ActiveSheet.Range("N" & i3) = 1` really writes the value 1 in that sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim dicos As Dictionary
Set dicos = new Dictionary

'Populate dicos....

For i = 2 To n 'n is the the number of rows
    If dicos.Exists(ws.Cells(i, 20).Value) Then
        ws.Cells(i, 14) = dicos.Item(ws.Cells(i, 20).Value) + 1
    Else
        ws.Cells(i, 14) = 1
    End If
Next
```

I believe the problem was that you didn't use `.Value` on the additive line, thus it was just putting 1 in there. When I tested your code as-posted I changed the +1 to a +4 and got 4 in `cells(i,14)` instead of 1.

Comment: Your observation about getting 4 when changing +1 to +4 is the key of the solution. Thank you,